# Role of feedback capacitor in nanoamp current source

Tags: current-source, feedback

I am designing a nano-amp current source to drive a capacitive load, which can vary from about 50 pF - 200 pF.

Analog Devices has a helpful application circuit in a [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/60812fd.pdf) (page 14) for the LT6082C op amp, copied below:

[image]

My question: What is the role and importance of the 0.01 uF capacitor and 100\$\Omega\$ resistor in the feedback path of the top amplifier?

The bottom two amplifiers form a differential amplifier that applies the voltage difference across the 10 M\$\Omega\$ sense resistor to the input of the 1k resistor at the negative input terminal of the top amplifier.

At very low frequencies, the 0.01 uF cap acts as an open circuit, and so that feedback path is not active. At higher frequencies, is this capacitor, along with the 100\$\Omega\$ resistor there for stability? If so, is it reasonably easy to explain how those elements increase the stability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At DC, the top op-amp’s feedback is provided by the differential amplifier.

At higher frequencies, the feedback becomes local, bypassing the diff amp, and the gain is reduced to 1.1.

The diff-amp is too slow to close the feedback loop around the top op-amp at higher frequencies. So the top has no phase margin left and will oscillate. By rerouting the feedback, at AC the top op-amp acts like an “almost” voltage follower and is thus stable.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as two feedback paths in parallel from the top of the 10 MΩ.

One is the short and obvious path via the 100 Ω and 0.01 uF. The other is more complex via the buffer and diff. amp. feeding the feedback node via 1 kΩ. At low frequencies, the 1 kΩ 'wins', but at high frequencies (where the impedance of the 0.01 uF is lower than the 1 k output drive of the diff. amp.), that path wins, thus avoiding any complex phase or gain behaviour of the 2-amplifier path, and simplifying stability concerns.